# Как в кавычки js вставить значение переменной php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, php5

index.php

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
       $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
x=$('.plane').position();
        x1=x.left;
        y1=x.top;
 localStorage.setItem('<?php $left=123;?>',x1);
 localStorage.setItem('<?php $top=12;?>',y1);       

      }
    });
 $('.plane').css('top',localStorage.getItem('<?php $top=12;?>')+'px');
$('.plane').css('left',localStorage.getItem('<?php $left=123;?>')+'px');
$('#rese').click(function(){
  localStorage.removeItem('<?php $left=123;?>');
  localStorage.removeItem('<?php $top=12;?>');
   $('.plane').css('top','0px');
     $('.plane').css('left','0px');               
});
```

Пока не работает, помогите исправить

Comment: Вы понимаете что делаете? Вы определяете переменные. Если вам нужно вставить переменную используйте `<?=$var;?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если переменные `$top`/`$left` уже определены в этом файле (или  файле, который может в себя включать данный файл), то остается их (переменные) отобразить через `echo` или сокращенный синтаксис. Пример

```
localStorage.setItem('<?= $left; ?>',x1); // localStorage.setItem('<?php echo $left; ?>',x1);
localStorage.setItem('<?= $top; ?>',y1); // localStorage.setItem('<?php echo $top; ?>',y1);
```